# Recaptcha not required

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner with Django. 
This is my code but I think that the recaptcha here in my contact form is not a required field. I mean that the user can send a feedback without selecting the Recaptcha.

**views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    form = FeedbackForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid(): 

        recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
        values = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        data = urllib.urlencode(values).encode()
        req =  urllib2.Request(url, data=data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
        ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

        if result['success']:
            form.save()
            message = u'You have feedback\nName: %s\nEmail: %s\nPhone: %s\nCountry: %s\nFeedback:\n%s' % (
            form.cleaned_data['name'], 
            form.cleaned_data['email'],
            form.cleaned_data['phone'],
            form.cleaned_data['country'],
            form.cleaned_data['feedback'])
            try:
                send_mail('NEW FEEDBACK', message, '', settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL) # to admin
                send_mail('THANK YOU for contacting us', 'We will be back to you promptly.', '', [form.cleaned_data['email'],]) # to user
                messages.info(request, 'SUCCESS! Your message has been sent!')
                form = FeedbackForm()
            except:
                messages.info(request, 'Sorry, can\'t send feedback right now.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.') 

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'active_page':'contact','form': form,})
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name  = forms.CharField(label = u'Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label = u'E-mail', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    email_verify = forms.EmailField(label=u"E-mail (again)", widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(label = u'Phone', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Optional','class':'form-control'}), required=False)
    country = forms.CharField(label = u'Country', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Optional','class':'form-control'}), required=False)
    title = forms.CharField(label = u'Title', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Optional','class':'form-control'}), required=False)
    feedback = forms.CharField(label = u'Message', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':3, 'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
            model = Feedback
            exclude = ['created_at',]
            fields = ['name', 'email', 'email_verify', 'phone', 'country', 'title', 'feedback']
```

Comment: post your `FeedbackForm` also

Comment: Done i added it

Comment: I don't see any recaptcha field in you feedback form. Are you including it directly in your html. Also have you considered using [this](https://github.com/ImaginaryLandscape/django-nocaptcha-recaptcha)

Comment: yes it is in the html, i use this website : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/21/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-django-site.html